# SecurityException running an ASP.NET in medium trust level on windows shared hosting

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server, visual-studio

I have an ASP.NET web form application  it is working fine locally, when I deploy it on the hostgator windows shared account it gives the the following error: [The Error Link](http://prestigerentacar.com/CarFleetGuide.aspx)

[SecurityException: That assembly does not allow partially trusted callers.]
   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.ObjectBuilder.EnterpriseLibraryFactory..cctor() +0

I contacted them & they say your application should run on medium trust level.

I believe the issue is with Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary this DLL should run in medium trust level.

Please advise on how to run the said DLL on medium trust level or any other solution to make the website run on shared hosting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recommended solution is to rebuild the Microsoft Enterprise Library components to contain the AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers() attribute and use your own version of this library.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/954274

Comment: Could you please to be more specific on how to rebuild the solution with Microsoft Enterprise Library components

Comment: You misunderstood. Its not about rebuilding your solution. You have to rebuild their solution! You have to install the Microsoft Enterprise Library with source code; modify the Microsoft source code (One additional line in each project to AllowPartialTrustedCallers). Finally you can use your custom version of the Enterprise Library in your project. Take a look: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664551